# "XY" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:AB"

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio

VisualStudio bugs me with those two errormessages:

> The name "SeverityToColorConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MYNAMESPACE".

and

> The name "ReadOnlyTextBoxLineExtendedUnit" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MYNAMESPACE".

I have a Styles.xaml in the toplevel of my application.

Simplified to the minimum it looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MYNAMESPACE">

    <local:SeverityToColorConverter x:Key="SeverityToColorConverter" />
    <local:SeverityToImageSourceConverter x:Key="SeverityToImageSourceConverter" />

    <Style TargetType="local:ReadOnlyTextBoxLineExtendedUnit" BasedOn="{StaticResource ErrProvErrorTemplateStyle}" />
    <Style TargetType="local:TextBoxLine" BasedOn="{StaticResource ErrProvErrorTemplateStyle}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Both, the `ReadOnlyTextBoxLineExtendedUnit` and the `TextBoxLine` are in the exact same directory. In their .xaml.vb code there is no namespace specified. Yet VS seems to find only the latter of those two. How can this even be possible?
The same goes for the converters. Some are recognized and same are not.
What is very important here is that the Object Browser finds ALL of those objects.

Maybe it is important to mention that I had a WinForms App that I slowly converted to WPF using compatibility tools from MS. Now I changed entirely to a WPF base app and will host some remaining WinForms. To do this task I manually reimported all files to the new app (maybe there would have been a better solution ...).
So I know for sure that my code should work. It has to be some VS crap ... or some issue with the new WPF host I don't understand ...

Yes I tried all the dirty tricks of switching to x86/x64. It solved some of the issues but those remain.

Best Wishes
Yatekii

Comment: If you have classes without namespace you are doing something wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by that? If I create a new component the .xaml.vb will contain only a `class mycomponent end class` and not a `namespace xy class mycomponent end class end namespace`. Also: the important part is that it does work with some components and does not with others.

Comment: You should, in general, not declare classes in the global namespace as far as i know. I don't know why it would not create a default namespace based on the directory you are in (or maybe that is implicit in VB? Not very familiar with that.).

Comment: Obviously the `clr-namespace` has to match the namespace your class is in. If they have no namespace you might might be in trouble.

Comment: Yes, normally the yinherit the default namespace. so everything else is in MYNAMESPACE without doing anything

Answer (score 1):

So after hours of struggle, trying restarts, switching x86/x64, cleaning the project etc. I found out that "Clean" your project for Visual Studio does not mean clean but rather "delete your exe". Same goes for the rebuild. Only the EXE is checked. Assemblies, object files, autogenerated designer files, everything stays there and stays broken.

In the end, deleting the obj and bin folders worked like a charm.
No syntactical errors, just Visual Studio not being at it's senses :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I restarted Visual Studio. Problem gone.